# Can ElasticSearch _suggest query return multiple fields?

Tags: elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I have the following mapping for an index in which I'm doing a suggest/autocomplete lookup and response.

```
"mappings": {
    "listing": {
        "_source": {
            "enabled": false
        },
        "dynamic": false,
        "properties": {
            "_all": {
                "enabled": false
            },
            "listingTitle": {
                "type": "completion",
                "index_analyzer": "str_index_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "str_search_analyzer"
            },
            "address": {
                "dynamic": false,
                "properties": {
                    "city": {
                        "type": "completion",
                        "index_analyzer": "str_index_analyzer",
                        "search_analyzer": "str_search_analyzer"
                    },
                    "stateOrProvince": {
                        "type": "completion",
                        "index_analyzer": "str_index_analyzer",
                        "search_analyzer": "str_search_analyzer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the endpoint and data for the request: site.dev:9200/listingsuggest/_suggest

```
{
  "result": {
    "text": "Minn",
    "completion": {
      "field": "address.city"
    }
  }
}
```

So this works for finding documents that match cities starting with Minn. The issue I'm having is I also want to return the stateOrProvince field value of each document matching "Minn". For example my result set comes back with the following matched words:

```
Minneapolis
Minnetonka
```

What I need it to do is return this:

```
Minneapolis, MN
Minnetonka, MN
```

The full response currently:

```
{
    _shards: {
        total: 1
        successful: 1
        failed: 0
    }
    result: [{
        text: Minn
        offset: 0
        length: 4
        options: [{
            text: Minnetonka
            score: 1
        } {
            text: Minneapolis
            score: 1
        }]
    }]
}
```

Desired full response if possible:

```
{
    _shards: {
        total: 1
        successful: 1
        failed: 0
    }
    result: [{
        text: Minn
        offset: 0
        length: 4
        options: [{
            text: Minnetonka, MN
            score: 1
        } {
            text: Minneapolis, MN
            score: 1
        }]
    }]
}
```

Is this, or some variation of that response, possible?

Comment: No, there is not anything to return multiple values for autocomplete, you'd need to index the state and the city as one value 'Minneapolis, MN' in the same autocomplete field.

Comment: Is there a way to return additional fields anywhere on the object/result? Doesn't have to be a concatenated string. The issue is we are using the MongoDB River plugin, so building the concatenated string isn't really an option... unless there is something magical in the river plugin that could handle this that I don't know about.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible! Try this:

```
PUT /listingsuggest
{
   "mappings": {
      "listing": {
         "_source": {
            "enabled": false
         },
         "dynamic": false,
         "properties": {
            "_all": {
               "enabled": false
            },
            "listingTitle": {
               "type": "completion",
               "index_analyzer": "standard",
               "search_analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "address": {
               "dynamic": false,
               "properties": {
                  "city": {
                     "type": "completion",
                     "index_analyzer": "standard",
                     "search_analyzer": "standard"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You don't need `address.stateOrProvince`.

Post some data:

```
POST /listingsuggest/listing
{
    "listingTitle" : "title1",
    "address" : {
        "city" : {
            "input" : ["Minneapolis"],
            "output" : "Minneapolis, MN"
        }
    }
}

POST /listingsuggest/listing
{
    "listingTitle" : "title2",
    "address" : {
        "city" : {
            "input": ["Minnetonka"],
            "output" : "Minnetonka, MN"
        }
    }
}
```

And use this query:

```
POST /listingsuggest/_suggest
{
  "listing" : {
    "text" : "Minn",
    "completion" : {
      "field" : "address.city"
    }
  }
}
```

It returns:

```
   "listing": [
      {
         "options": [
            {
               "text": "Minneapolis, MN",
               "score": 1
            },
            {
               "text": "Minnetonka, MN",
               "score": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
```